# Problems with Web Workers

Tags: node.js, worker

I have a React application that needs to use a Worker for heavy lifting. If I do a simple task it "postMessage" normally, but if it's the task I really want to happen, the worker doesn't even seem to be called!

----- The Work Test: -----

```
onmessage = function(e){
    postMessage("oi");
};
```

The caller:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    function startGenerationKeys() {
        const worker = new Worker('jobs/KeysPair.js');
        worker.postMessage("start");
        worker.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log(e.data);
        }
    }
    startGenerationKeys();
}, []);
```

----- The real Worker: -----

```
import NodeRSA from 'node-rsa';

onmessage = function(e){
    const keysPair = new NodeRSA({ b: 4096 });
    const pubKey = keysPair.exportKey('public').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
    const privKey = keysPair.exportKey('private');
    postMessage({
        pubKey,
        privKey
    });
};
```

The caller:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    function startGenerationKeys() {
        const worker = new Worker('jobs/KeysPair.js', {type: 'module'});
        worker.postMessage("start");
        worker.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log(e.data);
        }
    }
    startGenerationKeys();
}, []);
```

https://i.ibb.co/dmRHqxN/recording.gif

Comment: FYI NodeJs != React. Node runs on the server, React runs in the browser (and can be run on the server but since you're including a `useEffect` here you're running solely in the browser)

Comment: I was wrong, I already removed the word Node.JS from the question, I just wanted this worker to work in React, because I want the user's browser to create a key pair of 4096 for security reasons. And for some reason the Worker doesn't run with a more complex function.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the lines using node-rsa. Are you sure is supported by browser?

Comment: Without a worker I was able to normally create a pair of keys inside the useEffect of 1024, but the intention is to use a worker to create a more complex one. So yes in principle it is supported. I've tried to create a 1024 inside the worker but also no response! But it's weird even the console log doesn't work as seen in the gif!